# Python: Error while importing "emojize" from "emoji" package

Tags: python

I am trying to install "emoji" and then importing "emojize" but getting an error:

```
(base) Admin$ python --version
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(base) Admin$ pip install emoji
Collecting emoji
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/e7/cf76e0774b13459e61ffe16a042a35f42e292aeebba060b919c05b0854ab/emoji-0.5.0.tar.gz (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 795kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: emoji
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for emoji ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/5d/60/eb/49bb6f75caa1bd0b277d43bd14ac3ea1db3e5ed030d2013852
Successfully built emoji
Installing collected packages: emoji
Successfully installed emoji-0.5.0
(base) Admin$ from emoji import emojize
from: can't read /var/mail/emoji
(base) Admin$
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Umm, you have to type `from emoji import emojize` in a python script. It's not a bash command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to open the [Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/interpreter.html) also known a the  Python [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) you can see that it has been downloaded correctly. It should look like this:

```
 $ python3.7
 Python 3.7 (default, Sep 16 2015, 09:25:04)
 [GCC 4.8.2] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>>from emoji import emojize
 >>>
```

But emoji doesn't just exist magically in your machine. It exists in Python. So if Python is on your path you can just type in "python3.7" (as in the example above) and then it will start up the REPL, at which point you can type in from emoji import emojize and it should come back with no errors.

Also, I would highly recommend reading some Python documentation.

Comment: @Aran-Fey and @ C.Lewis. Thanks a lot for pointing out and guiding.